# TVirtualStringTree - setting column cells/nodes Alignment

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have a VirtualStringTree with a Header.Column set to `taLeftJustify` (default).

Is there a way to set the cells/nodes of that column to `taRightJustify` so that the nodes will be justified to the right, but the header column text will be justified to the left?

This is my desired result (in **column 1**):

[image]

I'm using a rather old VT version 4.5.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Column caption alignment use:

```
Header.Columns[x].CaptionAlignment := taLeftJustify;
```

and for nodes alignment:

```
Header.Columns[x].Alignment := taRightJustify;
```

x = your column

Comment: My old VT version (4.5.5) dose not have `CaptionAlignment` property. however after looking into version 5.3.0 I believe this is the correct answer, so I'm going to accept it. if I was using a newer VT version (which I can't at the moment) I would have figured it out myself :) Thanks.

Comment: Was trying to find when this property was implemented, no luck. Anyway, I'm glad you have the solution.

Answer (score 4):

In my old VT version, there is no `TVirtualTreeColumn.CaptionAlignment`, so I managed to use `OnAdvancedHeaderDraw` to draw my own columns captions. I set column 1 to `taRightJustify` and handle the header *Text* drawing myself for the desired column.

This code *might* be helpful for others, so I'll post it anyway:

```
type
  TVirtualTreeColumnsAccess = class(TVirtualTreeColumns);

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VST.Header.Options := VST.Header.Options + [hoOwnerDraw];
  VST.OnHeaderDrawQueryElements := VSTHeaderDrawQueryElements;
  VST.OnAdvancedHeaderDraw := VSTAdvancedHeaderDraw;
end;

procedure TForm1.VSTHeaderDrawQueryElements(Sender: TVTHeader; var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo;
  var Elements: THeaderPaintElements);
begin
  { Use OwnerDraw only for desired column(s)     }
  { other columns drawing will be handled by VST }
  if Assigned(PaintInfo.Column) and (PaintInfo.Column.Index = 1) then
    Elements := [hpeText];
end;

procedure TForm1.VSTAdvancedHeaderDraw(Sender: TVTHeader;
  var PaintInfo: THeaderPaintInfo; const Elements: THeaderPaintElements);
var
  DrawFormat: Cardinal;
  R: TRect;
begin
  { The event will fire only for the desired column(s) }
  if (hpeText in Elements) and Assigned(PaintInfo.Column) then
  with PaintInfo do
  begin
    DrawFormat := DT_LEFT or DT_TOP or DT_NOPREFIX;
    if Column.UseRightToLeftReading then
      DrawFormat := DrawFormat or DT_RTLREADING;

    R := TextRectangle;
    R.Left := PaintRectangle.Left + Column.Margin;

    TVirtualTreeColumnsAccess(Column.Owner).DrawButtonText(
      TargetCanvas.Handle, Column.Text, R,
      IsEnabled,
      IsHoverIndex and (hoHotTrack in Sender.Options)
        and not (tsUseThemes in Sender.Treeview.TreeStates),
      DrawFormat);
  end;
end;
```